# Displaying DOIs with the achemso package

Tags: doi, achemso

I'm using the achemso package (version 3.10h) for a submission to an ACS journal and I can't get DOIs to appear in the bibliography.  At the top of the file I have

```
\documentclass[journal = esthag,manuscript = article, layout = traditional]{achemso}
```

I can change some package options, such as whether the article title is displayed or the max number of authors displayed by using

```
\setkeys{acs}{articletitle = false}
\setkeys{acs}{etalmode = firstonly, maxauthors=1}
```

However, when I try to have DOIs displayed using

```
\setkeys{acs}{doi = true}
```

the program throws an error

```
Runaway argument?
{10.1021/ic9907718}\relax \mciteBstWouldAddEndPuncttrue \mciteSetBstM\ETC.
./achemso-demo.tex:381: File ended while scanning use of \doi@aux.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
l.381 \bibliography{achemso-demo}
```

I can duplicate this both in my document and in the achemso-demo.tex file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `achemso` which I'll correct shortly. For the present, add

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\doi}{%
  \begingroup
    \let\do\@makeother
    \dospecials
    \catcode`\{=1
    \catcode`\}=2
    \doi@aux
}
\makeatother
```

to your preamble. (The issue is a missing terminating space.)